# "at" command doesn't allow usage of lxterminal and other bash commands

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, bash, omxplayer

I am very new to the raspberry Pi and try to make like a "alarm Clock" with my Raspberry Pi Model 3 B.
For setting the song which it should play for a given time I use the "at" command.

The problem with this is that "at" doesn't execute the script properly when I use the "lxterminal" command like:

```
lxterminal -e omxplayer sampleFile.mp4
```

I use this to be able to exit the sample file with hotkeys.
Also different bash commands such as the usage of bash arrays don't work:

```
email_found=${output[0]}
```

When I call the script with "at" command like this:

```
at -f alarmClock.sh 17:21 05.06.2017
```

without the lxterminal it works.
I changed the mode of the file to be executable. Also it has the shebang.
Really can not figure out why it doesn't work.
Do you have an idea what the error exactly is and how to solve it?
Cheers!

EDIT:

As I found out this: https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=191251 solved my proplem by adding this: `export DISPLAY=:0.0` before in the line before I execute the music file.

Comment: If I get you right, because I haven't worked with wrapper scripts befor: I created a script `test.sh` which executes the other script `playmusic.sh` and schedule this with `at -f test2.sh 21:50 07.06.3027 &> /tmp/at_error.log`  It doesn't execute the command and in the logs it tells me "warning commands will be executed using /bin/sh"

Comment: I tried it again. and checking the error of each script executed `at -f test2.sh 8:27 08.06.2017 &> error.txt`    `test2.sh &> error2.txt`     and `lxterminal -e omxplayer sampleFile.mp4 &> error3.txt`  It still doesn't work but error3.txt gives me different information: "(lxterminal:3490): Gtk-WARNING **:cannot open display:"  DO you know more about this error?